# The descriptive narrative of literary history

Tags: meaning

Can anybody explain this sentence to me?

> you might be concerned with how this flowering came, with the descriptive narrative of literary history.

What does "with the descriptive narrative of literary history" mean here?

Comment: What phrase you do not understand?   "descriptive narrative"? "literary history"?

Comment: OP, it's important to always include [a reference to the original source](http://www.vqronline.org/american-renaissance) with attribution, and you ***must*** include a few sentences *around* the one in question to provide context. In this case, it's a pretentious art writer using characteristically overly florid and purple prose to say: "You might be wondering about the history behind this period of literature". That is, questions of who was involved, what they did, whom they influenced, as so on.

Comment: Let me also offer a word of warning: if you're not a native English speaker as well as reasonably familiar with latter 19th century American literature, you'll probably find that entire article hard going, and the book it is reviewing all but gibberish. Note that the article itself was written in the 1940s, and so even beyond the subject matter, it exhibits a literary style which is no longer common, and its idioms and tropes may create traps for the unprepared.

Comment: @DanBron **1)** There's no evidence that your link is OP's source; mahdi may be reading the original, or it may be a passage from a test. **2)** I think you’re very unfair to Matthiessen. He’s not indulging in 'florid and purple prose' but carefully defining his terms; and I see nothing in his style which could be described as ‘uncommon’ or ‘gibberish’. The 40s aren’t so long ago; hell, I was born in the 40s. The works he discusses may be heavy going for OP, but that’s another matter altogether.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Context is helpful:

> The half-decade of 1850-55 saw the appearance of *Representative Men* (1850), *The Scarlet Letter* (1850), *The House of the Seven Gables* (1851), *Moby-Dick* (1851), *Pierre* (1852), *Walden* (1854), and *Leaves of Grass* (1855). You might search all the rest of American literature without being able to collect a group of books equal to these in imaginative vitality. That interesting fact could make the subject for several different kinds of investigation. You might be concerned with *how* this flowering came, with the descriptive narrative of literary history. Or you might dig into its sources in our life, and examine the economic, social, and religious causes *why* this flowering came in just these years. Or you might be primarily concerned with *what* these books were as works of art, with evaluating their fusions of form and content. —F.O.Matthiessen,  [*American Renaissance*](http://books.google.com/books?id=tULy3pA-ZoQC&pg=PR7&dq=%22the+descriptive+narrative+of+literary+history%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=NFF7VJGvJ-mCsQSzsYCoDg&ved=0CC0Q6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=%22the%20descriptive%20narrative%20of%20literary%20history%22&f=false), OUP 1941

The author is distinguishing three different questions raised by the extraordinary fact that seven acknowledged masterpieces of American literature appeared virtually simultaneously. You might be concerned with

- *How* this flowering happened
- *Why* it happened ... or
- *What* the works were that constituted the flowering.

The phrase *with the descriptive narrative of literary history* is an alternative statement of what being **concerned *with*** the 'how' means, defines it in more detail:

- It is *descriptive*, reciting only documentable facts, not speculations (the same sense in which we speak of *descriptive linguistics*).
- It is *narrative* in form, reciting the facts as a coherent sequence of events.
- It is the approach characteristic of a particular genre of discussion, *literary history*, as opposed to *literary criticism*.

Comment: @Amphiteóth Yes; but the link is to a review of that work which does not include the entire quotation. I will provide a source.